# Andengine game force closes on resuming with changed device orientation

Tags: android, andengine

I have developed a game using `andengine` with PORTRAIT_FIXED `ScreenOrientation`. This is a problem occurred in tablets.

Briefly when while playing game > press power button to turn off the screen > press power button again to resume > lockscreen > change device orientation to landscape > unlock the lockscreen > activity not responding dialog

In phones this problem does not occur. But in tablets if I change the screen orientation of the device this `ANR` occurs. Please assist me with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in Manifest xml:

```
  <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```